# Druid Too much memory consumption

Tags: druid

I have deployed Druid Single server using command (./bin/start-micro-quickstart)

My server specification is 8vCPU and 32GB RAM (EC2 t2.2Xlarge) and also added 100GB SWAP
I'm trying to ingesting 27M records from kafka to Druid.

Now at this point I have 4M records shown in Druid Datasource with total size is 506 MB and segment are 5400 (Average Segment size is 92.99 KB)

And my Memory usage is

```
             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G         30G        248M         24K        207M         96M
Swap:           99G         78G         21G
```

My DataSource size is 506 MB So why RAM Consumption is 108 GB ?

And are those all segment is in memory?

Whice druid service uses CPU and Which Druid Service uses Memory?

Comment: Can you share your ingestion JSON?

Comment: @LiranFunaro Ingestion JSON contains 4M MySQL records coming from MySQL bin-logs, and MySQL table has ~50 columns. Druid ingesting data from Kafka.

Comment: But without the ingestion configuration, I won't be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

How many peon task you are running ? Since you are using kafka to ingest, I am assuming you are using superviser spec. If you have too many topics, and a supervisor spect for each topic, it will take memory. Check direct memory requirements. https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration/index.html